# Hashtable em powershell

Tags: powershell

desde já peço desculpa pela minha inexperiência!
Então, tenho a seguinte hashtable:

@{Name=UserAgent; Value=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0} @{Name=FlowTokenScenario; Value=Login} @{Name=UserAuthenticationMethod; Value=1} @{Name=RequestType; Value=Login:login} @{Name=ResultStatusDetail; Value=Success}

E precisava de fazer a selecção dos "value" em que o "name" seja UserAgent e discartar as outras.

Por Exemplo: $hash.value[0] retorna-me "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"

Eu gostava, se possível, algo do género: $hash.name['UserAgent'] e de alguma forma me retornar o value associado.

Desde já agradeço o vosso tempo!!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que resolvi o meu problema desta forma:

foreach ($key in $hash.getenumerator()) {
  if ($key.name -eq "useragent") {
    $key.value
    }
}

Não sei se foi a forma mais correta, mas parece que funcionou